# How to prevent the repeating country in Math.random() JavaScript or TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm adding a feature to the learning Europe Map game with angular 4. I have a function that populates the countries array from the regions and if and randomly displays the country name then it asks the user to find it.  a record as a point/value and I want to loop through all countries once even if the not correct user answers in the first iteration, the next cycle/iteration should start from whatever user didn't correct the answer.

**User Interface**
it is a web-based learning find map game/app. When the user opens the site it redirects to the login and automatically creates a username if it does not exist in that local machine/computer and shows the welcome to  ___ username!

**Welcome**

1. New Game
2. Achievements
3. High Score

**Select game mode**

1. Learning
2. Classic
3. Time

**Select regions**

1. Southern Europe
2. Baltic
3. South America etc

**Start the Game based on the selected regions**

then ask the random country name to find. If the user clicked the correct country it counts and moves to the next country to find.

**Note**
The countries and regions all come from the SVG file so, the image holds all regions and the countries with their own region.

**Code**

```
 populateCountriesArray(): void {
  this.selectedRegions.forEach(region => {
   const randomizedRegion = Array.prototype.slice.call(region.children);
   for (let i = randomizedRegion.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    [randomizedRegion[i], randomizedRegion[j]] = [
      randomizedRegion[j],
      randomizedRegion[i]
    ];
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < randomizedRegion.length; i++) {
    this.countries.push({
      name: randomizedRegion[i].id,
      selected: false,
      numCorrect: 0,
      numTries: 0,
      regionID: +randomizedRegion[i].attributes.region_id.nodeValue
    });
  }
});
}
```

## The goal should be like this:

**Iteration 1:**
Spain - Wrong (answer)
Italy - Right (answer)
Portugal - Wrong (answer)

**Iteration 2:**
Spain: Wrong (answer)
Portugal: Right (answer)

**Iteration 3:**
Spain: Right (answer)

Comment: If user answer is correct it should not ask again the same country name to next cycle. Thanks

Comment: Have you had a look at Array.filter()?

Comment: Thank you, Ben Steward, for a comment.
No, I'm a beginner in programming with javascript and angular. Can solve by Array.filter()?

Comment: @RabinRai: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Note that there should be an `edit` link under the question's tags.  This lets you edit the question, which means that while you can answer others' questions here in the comments, you can also edit the post to include additional information.  You probably should do that with what you posted in your first comment.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not following the behavior you're looking for.  Could you describe it in a little more detail from a user's perspective?  That is, what does the user see first.  What choice does she make?  After that, what does she see?  Etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do in this way: you initialize counties as a two-dimensional array ([region][country]). Randomize the order of countries (as you already did). Set first country in region array to start with.
And then just if user goes right then search for the next one. If all countries were right then go to next region.
That's a partial code that could be

```
currentRegionIndex = 0;
countrySelected = null;
populateCountriesArray() {
  this.counties = this.selectedRegions.map(region => 
    region.children
      .sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5)
      .map(c => ({
        name: c.id,
        correct: false,
        numTries: 0,
        regionID: +c.attributes.region_id.nodeValue
      }))
  );
  this.countrySelected = this.counties[0][0];
}
pick(point) {
  this.countrySelected.numTries++;
  if(checkCorrect(point, this.countrySelected)){
    this.countrySelected.correct = true;
  }
  if(!this.goNextCountry()) {
    this.currentRegionIndex++;
    if(this.countries.length === this.currentRegionIndex) {
      return alert('Finish!');
    }
    this.countrySelected = this.counties[this.currentRegionIndex][0];
  }
}
goNextCountry() {
  const region = this.counties[this.currentRegionIndex];
  const currentIndex = region.indexOf(this.countrySelected);
  // looking next not completed country from current index
  let next = region.find(c => !c.correct, currentIndex);
  if(!next) {
    // looking from array start
    next = region.find(c => !c.correct);
  }
  if(next) {
    this.countrySelected = next;
  }
  return next;
}
```